# Why both lists get modified after calling append() function on only one in python?

Tags: python, list

So I am learning python these days and got stuck on a problem. Here is my code.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = a
print(a)
print(b)
b.append(8)
print(a)
print(b)
```

The output is as follows.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8]
```

**Why** do both lists get modified even when I call it on only *b*? When we assign b = a, aren't we making a separate copy of that list?

Comment: You are using different names for the same list, not different lists. Use `b = list(a)` to copy it.

Comment: No sir, I don't want to know the procedure to copy, I want to know how the above code works and why both lists get modified?

Comment: @user: You are using different names for the same list.  If you call my dog Brutus, and I call him Bristo, you could pull on the tail of Brutus, and Bristo would feel pain.  They are the same dog.

Comment: @zondo If *a* is a function instead of list, it will still work the same way? I mean, b = a will still create a alias of *a* with name *b* right?

Comment: @user: That is correct, although usually, functions are not modified, so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for help :)

Comment: You may find it helpful to read this article, written by veteran SO member Ned Batchelder: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html).

Comment: Also see [Other languages have "variables", Python has "names"](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables).

Comment: @PM2Ring Awesome articles! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because python uses references for arrays, objects, etc.  If you want a copy of the array use `copy`:

```
import copy
b = copy.copy(a)
```

Comment: Okay I get this. But where can I find a detailed explanation on this?

Comment: You can check out https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements which talks about binding and names and how the python language implements them.